# What is the closed form for $ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n!)^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the closed form for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n!)^2}$?
And is there a closed form for $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n!)^k}$?

Edit: If there are no closed forms for the two series, how should I convert them into integrals? Now I know that $\displaystyle I_0(2)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n!)^2} = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{2\cos\theta}d\theta$, but is there an integral representation for $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n!)^k}$?

Comment: $I_0(\sqrt2)$ where $I_0$ is a modified Bessel function.

Comment: I think it is $I_0(2)$  instead of $I_0(\sqrt{2})$ right?

Comment: No `\displaystyle` in titles please.

Comment: An integral representation for $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n!)^k}$ seems to be an interesting question.  Voted to reopen.

Comment: It would help to add some context to this Question (as with others posted by the OP).  What motivates the interest in series of this form?  Is there a relationship underlying other recent posts by this OP about series and closed forms?  Such context may help motivate Readers to invest time in researching problems.

Comment: The function $u(x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n/(n!)^3$ solves the linear ODE $(x(xu')')'=u$. Curiously, solutions of  $(x(xu')')'=0$ would be easier to find: they are $P(\log x)$ with $P$ polynomial of degree less than $3$. Analogously for any $k$.

Comment: By definition, ${_0 F_{k - 1}}(; \mathbf 1; 1) = \sum_{n \geq 0} 1/(n!)^k$.