# Is there a way to calculate a power series between the geometric series and exponential series?

Tags: power-series

So I was messing around and realized that the geometric series and exponential series are really similar when written as a power series.

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n!)^0}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {x^n}=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n!)^1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x$$

By adding a simple exponential in to the denominator of the power series, you can switch between the two depending on if it is a $1$ or a $0$.  That leads to the question of, what would it be if it was a different value.

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n!)^a}= ???$$

What happens when $a$ is $.5$, or something else like $2$.

Comment: At least when $a=2$ you get the Bessel function $I_0$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2902724/442  and  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2866642/442

Comment: And also since the geometric series has radius of convergence $R = 1$ and the exponential series has $R = \infty$, what happens in between? At what threshold value of $a$ does $R$ become infinite?

Comment: @SammyBlack: With Stirling’s approximation of the factorial, the general term becomes

$$
(2\pi n)^{-\frac a2}\left(x\left(\frac{\mathrm e}n\right)^a\right)^n\;.
$$

For any $a\gt0$ the value in parentheses goes to $0$, so the terms eventually decay more than exponentially. So the radius of convergence is infinite for all positive $a$.